# Swift uiview on top of uitable

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift, uiview, uinavigationbar

I have a simple to do list using a uitable inside a top bar and I want to create a overlay menu activated from one of the buttons on the top bar.

How can I set that menu uiview on top overlay of the uitable custom cell?

I am using Swift in the latest Xcode for ios8.

> I am using the story board to try to insert the uiview or a ui container to set my menu. The idea is to initialise this view hidden and then a button on the top bar to show it. And this menu should have some uibuttons that I then want to create segways to different views. But I can't seem to be able to drag the view on top of the uitable in the storyboard. Is there a way? Even if using code?

Thanks.

Comment: Add what you have tried so far. Refer to [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question.

Comment: I am using the storyboard. But I can't insert the uiview. Just does not let me. It does let me put uiview in a new uiview controller.

Comment: Done. Do you think you can help me? I am new to xcode and swift. I come from php experience. Thanks.

Comment: I was reviewing your question and helping you improve it so that it gets upvotes and more people view it and you get helped faster. Go through the link in my first comment and try to create a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am using the storyboard. I don't have code to show. I don't want to be rude or break the rules. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are not breaking any rules or being rude. you are doing fine. Add a screen shot if possible.

Comment: Thanks. I'm on my mobile at the moment. But as soon as I get to my laptop I'll try to take a screenshot or a photo. Can you vote my problem up? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could programaticaly create a UIView:

```
var view2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: WIDTH, height: HEIGHT))
```

if you wan't to add buttons to the view you can do that:

```
var button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: WIDTH, height: HEIGHT))
button.titleLabel?.text = "ButtonTitle"
button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("functionToCallWhenClicked"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside) //To do something when the button is tapped
self.view2.addSubview(button)//To add the button the the view2
```

And then you add view2 to the screen:

```
self.view.addSubview(view2)
```

If you wan't to remove the view2 from the screen:

```
self.view2.removeFromSuperview()
```

Comment: Is that the only way? Can't I use the storyboard? Also, how would I control the visual design that way across multiple screen sizes and etc?

Answer (score 0):

==> here Given Code Try iy

===>declare awView

awView = [AdWhirlView requestAdWhirlViewWithDelegate:self];

awView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2,

self.view.frame.size.height-kAdWhirlViewHeight/2);

[self.view addSubview:awView];

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

```
CGRect newFrame = awView.frame;

newFrame.origin.x = 0;

newFrame.origin.y = self.tableView.contentOffset.y+(self.tableView.frame.size.height-kAdWhirlViewHeight);
awView.frame = newFrame;
```

}

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your answer to format it so it becomes more legible. Thanks.